# Как в anglesharp взять элемент, который содержит @

Tags: c#, anglesharp

У меня есть html, в нем есть mails, они не в ссылке, а просто в каком-то элементе текстом.

Как мне взять текст этого элемент, который содержит `@`.

```
<p>@sus.ru</p>
```

Сайты разные, у всех разные элементы, не только `<p>`.
Мне нужен универсальный способ. Например пройтись по каждому элементу, который содержит `@`. Но как это сделать в `anglesharp`

Comment: `p:contains('@')`

Comment: Так на сайтах не только p содержат mailы. Мне нужен способ, который пройдется по всем тегам, и найдет в каком теге лежит mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var nodes = doc.All.Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.NodeName == "#text" && n.TextContent.Contains("@"));
```